# Can we 'replace' a column from a pivot table created using 'pivottabler' package of r?

Tags: r, pivot-table

I am using the 'pivottabler' package to create some pivot tables in R.

Basically, the pivot tables I create have similar structure, only the column header changes.

For example, I have a data set containing the prices of fruits based on region and month. 
So I will create one pivot that will look like this:

```
Fruits   Nigeria   Laos   England
         Prices   Prices   Prices
Apple      1$       2$       3$
Mango      4$       5$       6$
Orange     7$       8$       9$
```

And another pivot table that will look this:

```
Fruits    Jan      Feb     March
         Prices   Prices   Prices
Apple      1$      1.5$      2$
Mango      4$      4.5$      5$
Orange     7$      7.5$      8$
```

Right now I am using two different codes to create both the pivots.

```
pt_country <- PivotTable$new()
pt_country$addData(Fruit_Prices) #Fruit_Prices is the data frame containing the data
pt_country$addColumnDataGroups("Countries")
pt_country$addRowDataGroups("Fruits")
pt_country$defineCalculation(CalculationName = "Prices")
pt_country$renderPivot()

pt_country <- PivotTable$new()
pt_country$addData(Fruit_Prices) #Fruit_Prices is the data frame containing the data
pt_country$addColumnDataGroups("Months")
pt_country$addRowDataGroups("Fruits")
pt_country$defineCalculation(CalculationName = "Prices")
pt_country$renderPivot()
```

I want to shorten the code length, since there will be multiple such pivot tables.

So, ideally I was looking for a solution that allows me to replace one column group with another without changes to other structures of code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of the pivottabler package.

There are currently only limited options to amend a pivot table after it has been calculated.

**More detail**

In your example, removing the columns would also remove the calculations, since in your R script the calculations are added after the columns.  Reapplying the calculations is then not possible, because the pivot table recognises that the calculations were added already (you get an error).  I will look at options to add flexibility in the future.

**Alternative approach**

One option to reduce the amount of code is to create a function which takes as a parameter the variable to show on the columns.  This function can then be easily called to create different variations of the pivot table:

```
createPivot <- function(columnGroupVariableName)
{
  pt <- PivotTable$new()
  pt$addData(bhmtrains)
  pt$addColumnDataGroups(columnGroupVariableName)
  pt$addRowDataGroups("TOC")
  pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TotalTrains", summariseExpression="n()")
  pt$renderPivot()
}

# create pivot tables with different variables on the columns
createPivot("TrainCategory")
createPivot("PowerType")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found a sort of workaround this problem.
Thought to mention it here just for sake.

The answer provided by @cbailiss is better in that it achieves the desired result in reduced lines of code and has a better comprehension and will be marked as the official answer.

```
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(bhmtrains)

pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TotalTrains", summariseExpression="n()")

pt$addRowDataGroups("TOC")

## Adding the required column for the pivot
Col <- pt$addColumnGroup() # Step1
Col_Data <- Col$addDataGroups("TrainCategory") # Step 2

pt$renderPivot()

## Removing the 'Col' group, thus deleting the added columns
Col$removeGroup()

## Repeating Step 1 and Step 2 for another column variable
Col <- pt$addColumnGroup() # Step1
Col_Data <- Col$addDataGroups("PowerType") # Step 2

pt$renderPivot()
```

The above lines of code worked for me and the method was found in the 'Irregular' vignettes at:
http://www.pivottabler.org.uk/articles/v11-irregularlayout.html